# How to handle addons including angularjs too

Tags: angularjs

I am creating an webapp which uses angularjs. And I found out that angular will not function normally when the angularjs source is included twice.

How can I handle with browsers that have addons including angularjs source too?

Comment: addons don't interfere with scripts loaded by a web page. You have nothing to worry about.

Comment: @JBNizet chrome extensions does. So does other browsers

Comment: What do you mean by `will not function normally ` ?

Comment: Chrome extensions do not work in the context of the page, with the exception of content scripts. You should provide more details of your problem if you want a solution

Comment: @MichaelP. All my on mouseover,click,mousedown events where triggered twice. Sometimes 4 times. Take angularjs batarang (chrome extension) as example. By using this addon it will fire my events twice

Comment: How are bound these event handlers? In a custom directive, or by using angular built-in ngMouseover, ngClick, ngMousedown?

Comment: @MichaelP. by using angular built-in functions ng-click etc. Custom directives are not called twice, because my app is handling it.

Answer (score 0):

Check you index.html file. Probably you have included two (or more) times the angularjs script:

```
<script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I included it once, but the addons included the source too so... How can I prevent conflicts with addons what I cannot edit?

Comment: Which addons you are using? Only Batarang?

Comment: Only angularjs-batarang is including the angularjs source too. When I remove the batarang addon my app will function normally. The app is developed for developers, so this can occur with multiple users.

Comment: How you installed batarang? Here batarang add only this script: chrome-extension://ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/dist/hint.js
I installed from here https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk/related

Comment: first enable batarang in the developer console, and type "angular" without the quotes in the 'console' tab

Comment: As I said before here Batarag don't add another angular js script in the dom.. Can you take a screenshot? Or show us the code please

Comment: It does not manipulate the dom, it is done within the addon scope. But the javascript code is also available on the website your using.Thus global

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72003/discussion-between-ismail-and-manzapanza).